# Issues Posting to Database with cURL

Tags: php, html, mysql, curl, mysqli

**UPDATED AS OF 11/16/15 11:55pm PST**

Below you will find the code.

I am trying to get this to retrieve JSON data, and post the values to my database.

JSON Structure and in which order is being output...

```
[{
    "record_locator": "value",
    "status": "value",
    "area": "value",
    "region": "value",
    "name": "value",
    "position":"value",
    "phone_": "value",
    "project_manager": "value",
    "ipad_email": "value",
    "email": "value",
    "team_leader": "value",
    "regional": "value",
    "title": "value",
    "start_date": "value",
    "employee_id_number": "value",
}]
```

For easy eyes...

$VAR = MY TABLE KEY = JSON KEY

```
$area   =area   =area
    $email  =email  =email
    $ipad_email =ipad_email =ipad_email
    $empid  =empid  =employee_id_number
    $fullname   =fullname   =name
    $manager    =manager    =If Clause
    $mobilenumber   =mobilenumber   =phone_
    $record_locator =record =record_locator
    $status =status =status
    $region =region =region
    $position   =position   =position
    $project_manager    =project_manager    =project_manager
    $team_leader    =team_leader    =team_leader
    $regional   =regional   =regional
    $title  =title  =title
    $startdate  =startdate  =startdate
```

I've done a simple echo test of the value and they're grabbing it, just for some reason its not posting to the database. I cant figure it out sadly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
             <html>
                <head>
                <style>
                td {
                    text-align:center;
                    border: 1px solid black;
                }
                </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                <div style="margin-top:5%; width:300px; margin:auto; border: 1px solid black; padding:3px;"><center><p id="container">Loading...</p></div>
                <?php

                $error_msg = "";
                        $url="someurl.com";

                         $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       

        $json = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $rdata = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    $c=0;
    $repverified = 0;

    foreach ($rdata as $data) { 

    //  Assigned key            JSON KEY 
    $user_rl    = $rdata[$c]['record_locator'];
    $status = $rdata[$c]['status'];
    $area   = $rdata[$c]['area'];
    $region = $rdata[$c]['region'];
    $fullname   = $rdata[$c]['name'];
    $position   = $rdata[$c]['position'];
    $mobilenumber   = $rdata[$c]['phone_'];
    $project_manager    = $rdata[$c]['project_manager'];
    $ipad_email     = $rdata[$c]['ipad_email'];
    $email  = $rdata[$c]['email'];
    $team_leader    = $rdata[$c]['team_leader'];
    $regional   = $rdata[$c]['regional'];
    $title  = $rdata[$c]['title'];
    $startdate  = $rdata[$c]['start_date'];
    $empid  = $rdata[$c]['employee_id_number'];


        if(
            $fullname       == $rdata[$c]['project_manager'] || 
            $fullname       == $rdata[$c]['team_leader'] || 
            $fullname       == $rdata[$c]['regional'] || 
            $fullname       == $rdata[$c]['director']) 
                {
                $manager = 'YES';
                } 
        else {
                $manager = 'NO';
             }

            // Insert the new user into the database 
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO members (
    record,
    status,
    area,
    region,
    fullname,
    manager,
    position,
    mobilenumber,
    project_manager,
    ipad_email,
    email,
    team_leader,
    regional,
    title,
    startdate,
    empid

    )
    VALUES (
    ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

   $insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

    // Insert the new user into the database
    if ($insert_stmt)
    {
        $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssss',$user_rl,$status,$area,
                $region,$fullname,$manager,$position,$mobilenumber,
                $project_manager,$ipad_email,$email,$team_leader,
                $regional,$title,$startdate,$empid);

        // Execute the prepared query.
        if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
            header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
        }
    }
    }

    echo    '<div>Check to ensure we are grabbing the values</div>';
    echo    '<td>'. $user_rl    .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $status .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $area   .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $region .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $fullname   .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $manager    .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $position   .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $mobilenumber   .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $project_manager    .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $ipad_email .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $email  .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $team_leader    .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $regional   .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $title  .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $startdate  .'</td><br>';
    echo    '<td>'. $empid  .'</td><br>';


        $c++;


        echo "<script>document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'Registration Completed!<br><b> Active Users will now be visible</b>';</script>";
        ?>
```

Added an echo to double check we're grabbing the values.
Success! We are!

```
echo    '<div>Check to ensure we are grabbing the values</div>';
echo    '<td>'. $user_rl    .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $status .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $area   .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $region .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $fullname   .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $manager    .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $position   .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $mobilenumber   .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $project_manager    .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $ipad_email .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $email  .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $team_leader    .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $regional   .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $title  .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $startdate  .'</td><br>';
echo    '<td>'. $empid  .'</td><br>';
```

DB SCHEME

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `memberss` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `empid` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `record` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `area` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `region` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `fullname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `position` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mobilenumber` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `project_manager` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ipad_email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `regional` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `startdate` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in logs?

Comment: Unfortunately, I wish. But to the answer Nope :( @AG21

Comment: grab user details via JSON from url @AG21

Comment: Are you getting expected result in `$rdata`?

Comment: Correct. I will also update the OP with the structure of the JSON and in which order the key:value is being displayed. @AG21

Comment: Is the table name correct `memberss` in insert query?

Comment: That is correct. the Table is set for memberss as a testing table.

Comment: I have updated my OP with a Echo test, which passes. And also restructured the order of the var, and the insert to match the json data... Still not adding to the DB, but everything else to check out. @AG21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have figured out what I did wrong.**

I wasnt passing enough

`VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

I was also not binding enough strings.

`$insert_stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssss'` to match my

`if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (values)"))`

**This project is done, on to the next...**

Answer (score 1):

I have changed `insert` query and `bind_param` as below and it worked :

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO memberss (
    record,
    status,
    area,
    region,
    fullname,
    manager,
    position,
    mobilenumber,
    project_manager,
    ipad_email,
    email,
    team_leader,
    regional,
    title,
    startdate,
    empid

    )
    VALUES (
    ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    $insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

    // Insert the new user into the database
    if ($insert_stmt)
    {
        $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssss',$user_rl,$status,$area,
                $region,$fullname,$manager,$position,$mobilenumber,
                $project_manager,$ipad_email,$email,$team_leader,
                $regional,$title,$startdate,$empid);

        // Execute the prepared query.
        if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
            header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
        }
    }
```

**Note : Rest of the code is same.**

Comment: @LeviZoesch : I only changed the order in `insert` query and updated `bind_param` function call with `sssssssssssssssi` with the same order as `insert`.

Comment: Please check your database table, it should have the same columns. Will you please add your table structure? @LeviZoesch

Comment: Updated OP with my DB table scheme

Comment: As per database schema, `empid` is varchar so please change `sssssssssssssssi` to `ssssssssssssssss` and then check. I have also updated my answer.

Comment: Nope. I have updated the OP with my attempt from your answer. Maybe i placed something wrong???

Comment: @LeviZoesch : I am still not getting your problem. At my end its working fine.

Comment: It is not posting the values to the Database. Would you like to get on a screenshare, and I can show you?

Comment: Have you changed `bind_param` as per my updated comment?

Comment: @LeviZoesch : Where is `$mysqli` connection created ? Is it included in any file? `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "test");`

Comment: include_once 'db.php';
include_once 'active-config.php'; yes I have them, i just didnt insert them into the post.

Comment: <?php
include_once 'active-config.php';
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

Comment: In insert query table name is `members`. Is this correct now?