# If Else Echo JSON array check

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, if-statement

I have a JSON array that I am pulling values from per `$vars`. Within the JSON data are going to be some key words that I am looking for. I have a single `if` `else` that looks like:

*(demonstration purposes)*

```
if( $FullName == $Data[$c]['manager'] $FullName == $Data[$c]['leader'] || $FullName == $Data[$c]['helper']) {
    $cheapLabor = 'NO';
} else {
    $cheapLabor = 'YES';
}
```

That works great however, now I want to define more specifically some `if` `else` points on status points which would represent their employement status. Each Emp Status is based on a group.

I would need it to check from the top of the food chain, then go downward to check if `status = x`. If it does then `$cheapLabor = 'y'; else $cheapLabor = 'z';`

I tried doing it, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is what I am working with:

```
$repData = json_decode($json, TRUE);    
$c = 0;
$var = $repData[$c]['column'];

if($FullName == $repData[$c]['ceo']) {
    $groups = '[13]';
} else {
    $groups = '[5]';
}                                                   

if($FullName == $repData[$c]['director']) {
    $groups = '[10]';
} else {
    $groups = '[5]';
}

if($FullName == $repData[$c]['regional']) {
    $groups = '[9]';
} else {
    $groups = '[5]';
}   

if($FullName == $repData[$c]['project_manager']) {
    $groups = '[8]';
} else {
    $groups = '[]';
}   

if($FullName == $repData[$c]['team_leader']) {
    $groups = '[6]';
} else {
    $groups = '[5]';
}   

if($FullName == $repData[$c]['rae']) {
    $groups = '[5]';
} else {
    $staus = '[5]';
}
```

Shomz Answer partial working...

```
$groups = '[4]'; // new hire group default, to be overwritten if a user has the correct title within Table.
$roleGroups = array(
                    'regional' => '[7]',
                    'team_leader' => '[6]',
                    'RAE' => '[5]'                  
                    );  
foreach ($roleGroups as $role => $groups) {  // go through all the Position Titles
    if ($FullName == $repData[$c][$role]) { // see if there's a match
        $repGroup = $groups;                  // if so, assign the group
    } 
 }
```

It sets team_leader and regional correctly but anything else just sets it as regional group.

Just realized that its actually rewriting the value.

Comment: Could you be more clear on how the above code isn't working? As in what results you are getting and what you expected? One note is that the `'[]'` looks like it should be `'[5]'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is overwriting `$groups` in every if-statement. You probably want to rewrite that in a switch/case statement with a default value being `[5]`.

Let's say the first if is true, so `$FullName == $repData[$c]['ceo']` is true and `$groups` becomes `[13]`. In the next line, there are two choices:

- either a person is a director (AND a CEO, but it doesn't matter, see why below)
- or a person is not a director (could be a CEO)

In **both** cases, `$groups` will either get a value of `[10]` or `[5]`, meaning that no matter what happened inside the statement above, this statement will overwrite it. Thus, only your last if statement is able to produce results you might expect.

---

> "Only one group per role"

In that case a simple switch/case statement will work:

```
switch($FullName){

  case ($repData[$c]['ceo']):
    $groups = '[13]';
    break;                                          

  case ($repData[$c]['director']):
    $groups = '[10]';
    break;

  // etc... for other roles

  default: 
    $groups = '[5]';
    break;
}
```

---

Or you can go even simpler and use an associative array to combine roles with group numbers. For example:

```
$roleGroups = array('ceo' => '[13]', 'director' => '[15]', etc);
```

Then simply see if there's a match:

```
$groups = '[5]'; // default, to be overwritten if a role is found below
foreach ($roleGroups as $role => $group) {  // go through all the groups
    if ($FullName == $repData[$c][$role]) { // see if there's a match
        $groups = $group;                   // if so, assign the group
    }
 }
```

Hope this makes sense. Either way, `$groups` will have the number of the role if role is found, 5 otherwise.

Comment: Answer is a little vauge. can you give me a little more ? @Shomz

Comment: Sure, I was already writing more when you wrote that comment. :)

Comment: Okay, I understand the logic, but not sure how I would piece that together. Do you mind showing me a snippet of what it would look like? I appreciate your help and time to answer this question :) @Shomz

Comment: Alright, tell me is it possible for a person to have more than one function?

Comment: The user is defined to a 'group' per their 'role' within the company. Only one group per role, however there could be multiple people with the same 'role' @Shomz

Comment: Awesome, let me give it a shot and I'll let you know what happens :) with associative array which would be suggested? How would that look? @Shomz

Comment: I am getting a syntax error on  ` case $repData[$c]['ceo']):` @Shomz

Comment: Forgot an opening bracket - I'm writing this from my head. :)  Wasn't meant to be copied directly, just to give you an idea. Added the array version as well.

Comment: I couldn't get the associative way to work? It actually broke the script @Shomz

Comment: And the error is...? As I said, I'm giving you solutions, not the fully baked code.

Comment: I dont have error reporting setup properly to give me the error :/ It works perfectly, just not when I try the associative way. @Shomz

Comment: Just put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` above it. Have you removed the `etc` parts from the code and added real stuff?

Comment: Yes I have tried adding real stuff. Tried this as a test and it wont work. $roleGroups = array('regional' => '[1]', 'team_leader' => '[2]');

$groups = '[5]'; // 
foreach ($repData[$c] as $role => $group) {
    if ($FullName == $role) {
        $groups = $group;
    }
 }

Comment: Ah, you copied it before I polished it... Try the latest version. But even this shouldn't break the code, though, see: http://ideone.com/5OnYnF

Comment: Okay, I had a few bugs but cleaned those up. When I have the polished version in it kicks me an error `Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param() in /home/../../../filename.php on line 105` LINE 105 is         `$stmt->bind_param('s');,`

Comment: But it does not kick that error when I dont have that piece in @Shomz

Comment: I have no idea what's in filename.php, no idea what on line 105 and no idea what parameters your statement expects... how do you expect me to help you? :)

Comment: Give me a minute, I think I know what I did. I appreciate your help and patients :)

Comment: No problem, man... I *assume* it might be related to that string `'[5]'`, maybe you need just an array or an integer.

Comment: Its not allowing me to INSERT INTO. The insert statement results in an echo'd error for each value it attempts to input. It does this on both version that you posted to do the group check. Let me see if I can just set a value to it without the brackets. @Shomz

Comment: Yeah, try to match the output to what you had before.

Comment: I have it working, but as soon as I try any of the attemps you gave it doesnt insert. All attempts fail and do not result in errors when I try your methods @Shomz

Comment: Again, I have no idea what you were and are sending to the query... Match the output of my code to what you had working.

Comment: From previous questions I had on this script it will give you an outline of wha tI have and maybe you can see where I am goign wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751237/issues-posting-to-database-with-curl @Shomz

Comment: No, it's a bit too much for this question. The comment log is bigger than any other question here. I gave you the answer to what you originally asked for (and more), but we're going way off topic and it won't be helpful to anyone more. I suggest you open a new question, but first try to debug it yourself by comparing/matching the parameters.

Comment: You're welcome, did you figure out what was the difference?

Comment: I have it partially working. However, its setting the default of it doesnt find that title just sets 6's 7's I'll add to my OP what I have right now thats partially working. @Shomz

Comment: Wait, I just realized that its actually rewriting the value within the column. what I have is in OP...